# Function and Function()

Tags: flutter, dart

What is difference between  Function and  Function() in Dart/Flutter?
for example in such  a code
final Function x;
final Function() x;

Comment: function is the function x kind of like stored in a variable, while the function () x actually is the calling or invoking of the function to start its code.

Comment: @BrentHarris `Function() x` is not invoking any function.  It is declaring `x` to be a function that takes zero arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [the `Function` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Function-class.html), it is:

> The base class for all function types.

A variable declared with type `Function` therefore can be assigned *any* function.  However, you won't get any type-safety when invoking it.

Meanwhile a `Function()` type is a function with an unspecified (i.e., `dynamic`) return type and that takes zero arguments.